# Imagemagick - JPG And PNG extension not working

Tags: imagemagick

I have installed ImageMagick-6.5.7-8 and ghost script 8.64 on ubuntu. They are installed successfully but JPG and PNG extension not working here. GIF extension working successfully.

I have installed two other additional packages for these `jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz`  and `libjpeg62-dev` but still now working these two extensions.

I executed below command to see supported file formats:

```
Identify -list format
```

It show me all the file formats I check for the GIF, PNG and JPG extension but only GIF extension mode is showing rw+ but for PNG and JPG its showing rw-.

Does it matter that means extension is not enable here?

After installation of these additional packages do we need to re-compile existing image magick code?

Did anyone faced this issue before? Please can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's wrong with the distro packages?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will fix the issue, but I have had this kind of problems previously with ImageMagick (a long time ago, I would think they have fixed the issue), and the trick was to capitalize (or uncapitalize?) the extensions. Maybe give it a try.